# Linking Tasks & Appointments in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook

In Outlook 2013 you can create one or more appointments from a task and see the list of linked appointments in the task. The task details are also shown in the appointment.
It is also possible to insert the task as a shortcut into the appointment via 'insert outlook item' and then searching through the list of tasks (including completed!). And similarly the appointment into the task. This eventually gives you a quick link between them.

Is it possible to set up these links more easily?

Comment: Use http://www.superuser.com web site for non-programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. The Links property was deprecated in Outlook. See [What's new for Outlook 2013 developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx) for more information.

Anyway, use [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) web site for non-programming questions

Comment: Sorry! slip of concentration. Feel free to zapp this thread. Thanks